# Track progress (using JavaScript) of flv (or swf) loaded into swf

Tags: javascript, flv

Is this possible? How to do it?
Basically I need to track if video was watched fully, and send progress into database via AJAX, but stuck on tracking FLASH.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to use the ExternalInterface class inside the code of the swf.

Whenever, there is more data loaded for a video, a progressEvent is generated in swf.
When this progress event happens, then you will have to use ExternalInterface, which allows you to call a function in Javascript.

Lets assume, you have a javascript function,

```
function flvLoadProgressInSwf(percentage)
{
   $.ajax()//sending percentage to the server.
}
```

To call this function , from within flash, you will have to use the following command:

```
ExternalInterface.call('flvLoadProgressInSwf',percentageLoaded);
```

where percentageLoaded, can be anything from a sting to a complex object.

Incase you do want some more help, do paste your code.
Thanks,  Neeraj

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help - I just missed one fact - swf is a result file of programme - so I have no access to internal code. It shows video + slides of powerpoint presentation ( programme is called Lecturnity) I have this 'presentation' on page and need to track if students watched that. so would be great if I can record start and stop of internal flv.    And one more thing - in console in FF I can see: "time 15:32:38.140 :: Thumb.x: 34; Thumb.width: 14;" but no idea how to get those to my vars.